# Can Exit with this code

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I'm new to Java's ArrayList. I had a problem exiting statement when I called a class method
to return to the main menu after LookUp.searchstudent(iRegistered);

```
else if (choice==2) {
    //statement 
}
else if (choice==3) {
    System.out.println(" Keywords to Search");
    LookUp.searchstudent(iRegistered);
}
System.out.println("");
choice=menu();
```

here my class method,this searches data on my ArrayList

```
public class LookUp {
    public static Records searchstudent(ArrayList<Records> student) {
        Scanner inputN = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = inputN.nextLine();

        for (Records s : student) {
            if (s.getIdent().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println(s);

            } else if (s.getfirst().equals(name)) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        return searchstudent(student);
    }

}
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you've got?

Comment: I need help how to exit and return to my main menu.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling your method again and again, you need to return a `Records` instead of call `searchstudent()` method again.

**For Example:**

```
for(Records s: student) {
    // code
    return s;
}
```